# Spring render many many view for one page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hello  I am using spring mvc and my page consist of 2 columns left and right. I want that left side is rendered from one controller and right side is rendered another one. How to accomplish that. Fore example in the right side here is login form which renders from LoginController but the left side changes all time. How to accomplish it with spring mvc framework.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect when you submit the login form: the whole page reloaded or only the right hand side?

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC is not inherently a component-oriented framework, like you seem to want. Some different approaches that might suit you

- Client-side aggregation. Load your different "components" (left, right) using AJAX
- Using some more template/component-oriented rendering framework. I like [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) and breaking out logic in Preparers (analogous to Controllers in Tiles). Or you can use JSF 2. I wrote a bootstrap/tutorial on [Spring MVC 3 and JSF 2](http://papweb.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/spring-mvc-3-jsf-2-with-maven-2-and-tomcat/) a while back that might be interesting for you.
- Go full-on with a component-oriented framework like JSF 2, Tapestry or Wicket.

Comment: We used to work with sitemesh (http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/) for things like that, but it seems to be quite dead :-(.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to implement this. What are your exact requirements? You can try:

1. [Portlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portlet%5d) - render two portlets, each is rendered separately. Probably an overkill if this is needed only in this one place.
2. AJAX - Render an empty page first and fetch both views separately using AJAX. See [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).
3. `<iframe/>` - embed iframes with two different target URLs.
4. Use component-oriented framework (I personally like [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/)).

None of these approaches are tied Spring MVC or even Java.

Comment: good answers, but my situation is like that. I am using tiles for splitting the pages. in the left side here is login bar wich renders from login controller in the right side here list of /movies from Movie controller, when u go movies you see movies in the right panel but in the left panel here apeears login bar, So i can not call controller action from the view. How to render two controller action for one page?

Comment: I can not accomplish with spring itself??